# Switch Data connection on Dual SIM phone

Tags: android, sdk, dual-sim

Is there any possibility to switch data connection between SIM cards on Android 5.0.2 ? I want my app to turn on/off the internet connection on first or second SIM card.

Comment: I have the HTC One M8 Dual SIM so maybe there is any HTC API for this.

Comment: Maybe on API 22 there is a solution ?

Comment: How to download [this](https://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/download-install) SDK from HTCdev site. There is nothing there !?